# Hair doesn't follow armature

Tags: armature, hair

Hello to the Blender comunity.
The hair of eyebrows and eyelash doesn't follow the movements of my mesh.
I know is because armature is not first.
After having a hard time trying I finally got the form of eyelashes and eyebrows that I wanted and that's why I don't want make them again.
There is any way to move the hair settings after armature without making hair again?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to have at least three questions in there.  Can you separate them out and make them clear for us?

Comment: The question is:  It is possible to move the particle system after armature (in Editor panel: add modiffier) without deleting it?